# How to cheaply fractionalize certain rare NFTs in a collection?

Tags: nft, erc-721, dao

I wanted to fractionalize certain rare NFTs in a collection. I.e a collection with total 5000 NFTs, 4000 with normal minting (1 owner) and 1000 NFTs that are each fractionalized (100 shares).
Also the rare NFTs are not worth millions thus wanted a economical method to achieve this, i.e a single smart contract that can do this.

I have been told it is possible with a DAO, but unclear how to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can have two `mint` method. first one works as usual to mint only one token per call, but second one `mint10` only works after 4000 tokens sold and will mint 10 tokens per call.

Comment: How does this fractionalize the rare ERC721 tokens?

Comment: Each contract is for just a collection and two or more collections cant be in the same contract or set a trait named collection to each token metadata to make them different from others